# how to get an image to show in a formtastic :radio, :collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, formtastic

I can't get an image to show in a Formtastic form with radio buttons. Here's my form. The :activity_id, :as => radio is the issue:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @event do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :date, :as => :string, :input_html => { :class => 'jquery-ui-date'} %>
    <%= f.input :date, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :id => 'date-alt'} %>
    <%= f.input :activity_id, :as => :radio, :collection => Activity.all %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit, :as => :button %>
    <%= f.action :cancel, :as => :link %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

That works fine as far as showing the radio button, the activity name, and saving correctly on submit. But I need to show the image that goes with the activity because most of my users cannot read and must rely on images and TTS. I've got the images showing in my other views.

I've tried dozens of combinations of things with :hint, and :wrapper_html, and image_tag and so on. So many variations I've become scrambled in the brain-pan.

A sample attempt:

```
<%= f.input :activity_id, :as => :radio, :collection => Activity.all, :hint => f.template.image_tag(f.object.image_url(:thumb)) %>
```

This gives me an "undefined method `image_url'" error. Yet this :hint works fine elsewhere.

I'll switch back to a standard html.erb view if that helps, but my problem there was a "stringify_keys" error I was unable to solve.

There's gotta be a way. Please? Thanks much. . .

Comment: Why can't you use:hint => f.template.image_tag(@event.image_url(:thumb))

Comment: @iouri -- that gives me this error: undefined method `image_url'. That's the main error I keep getting.

Comment: Assuming that you are using paperclip, did you run migrations and did you add has_attached_file to your model? Is it also in attr_accessible?

Comment: @iouri -- I'm using carrierwave. Yep, all migrations have run and my models are saving images to my drive in dev and to Amazon S3 in production. The thing is, I don't get that error in my other views, using that same image_url and surrounding code.

Comment: Is @event an existing record or new record?

Comment: the problem is happening in the view for creating a new @event.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16850/discussion-between-iouri-and-charliemagee)